Resolving virtual host local domain
My goal
When I go to http://my-local.dev it should resolve http://localhost:3000
My configuration

I'm using Windows 11 with WSL (Ubuntu 22.04)

/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       my-local.dev

ls /etc/ngnix/sites-available
default
my-local.dev.config

ls /etc/ngnix/sites-enabled
default
my-local.dev.config (symbolic link to /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-local.dev.conf)

my-local.dev.config
server {
listen 80;
server_name my-local.dev;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}

sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Behaviour

I put http://localhost:3000 in browser => resolved correctly
I put http://my-local.dev in browser => connection refused
In terminal within Ubuntu curl my-local.dev => resolves HTML from my app

What I have tried
In system32 hosts file on Windows I added:
127.0.0.1       my-local.dev
::1             my-local.dev

And now when I do curl my-local.dev from Windows CMD, I get resolved HTML of Ngnix default page and from the browser it still doesn't work (connection refused)
Please help me to resolve this. I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.
Thank you in advance for your help.

This look like a permission error, check the permission of the second page and be sure they allow connexion

@Maslie I'm not sure what permissions are you talking about, but permissions of my-local.dev.config are exactly the same as default

I had a similar issue during my studies where if you don't gave the permission to view the file for the user, they wont be able to view it at all
